# Scala quickSort 10x slower when using Ordering[T]

Tags: performance, scala, sorting

I was doing some sorting of integer indices based on a custom Ordering.  I found that the Ordering[T] used here makes the sort at least 10 times slower than handcrafted quickSort using direct calls to the compare method.  That seems outrageously costly!

```
val indices: Array[Int] = ...

class OrderingByScore extends Ordering[Int] { ... }

time { (0 to 10000).par.foreach(x => {
  scala.util.Sorting.quickSort[Int](indices.take(nb))(new OrderingByScore)
})}
// Elapsed: 30 seconds
```

Compared to the hand crafted sortArray found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/benchmarking-scala-against) but modified to add an `ord: Ordering[Int]` parameter:

```
def sortArray1(array: Array[Int], left: Int, right: Int, ord: Ordering[Int]) = ...

time { (0 to 10000).par.foreach(x => {
  sortArray1(indices.take(nb), 0, nb - 1, new OrderingByScore)
})}
// Elapsed: 19 seconds
```

And finally, same piece of code but using exact type instead (`ord: OrderingByScore`):

```
def sortArray2(array: Array[Int], left: Int, right: Int, ord: OrderingByScore) = ...

time { (0 to 10000).par.foreach(x => {
  sortArray2(indices.take(nb), 0, nb - 1, new OrderingByScore)
})}
// Elapsed: 1.85 seconds
```

I'm quite surprised to see such a difference between each versions!

In my example, indices array is sorted based on the values found in another Doubles array containing a combined scores. Also, the sorting is stable as it use the indices itself as a secondary comparison. On a side note, to make testing reliable, I had to "indices.take(nb)" within the parallel loop since sorting modifies input array. This penalty in negligible compared to the problem that brings me here.  Full code on gist [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18ef9692e91443217a09).

Your suggestions are much welcomed to improve on.. But try not to change the basic structure of an indices and scores arrays.

Note: I'm running within scala 2.10 REPL.

Comment: Perhaps it's boxing and unboxing cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `scala.math.Ordering` is not specialized. So every time you call the compare method with a primitive like `Int`, both arguments of type `Int` are being boxed to `java.lang.Integer`. That is producing a lot of short-lived objects, which slows things down considerably.

The [spire library](https://github.com/non/spire) has a specialized version of Ordering called [spire.algebra.Order](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/b63cbda6d55cde769bb87dc6293d018280d9a20b/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/Order.scala) that should be much faster. You could just try to substitute it in your code and run your benchmark again.

There are also [sorting algorithms](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/b63cbda6d55cde769bb87dc6293d018280d9a20b/core/shared/src/main/scala/spire/math/Sorting.scala) in spire. So maybe just try those.

Basically, whenever you want to do math with primitives in a high performance way, spire is the way to go.

Also, please use a proper microbenchmarking tool like [Thyme](https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme) or [JMH](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh) for benchmarks if you want to trust the results.

Comment: The API documentation might be misleading here.  Ordering[T] defines 'abstract def
compare(x: T, y: T): Int'..     In my view, this should use direct type passing instead of boxing.

Comment: For the record, using spire and their Order[Int] specializations lead to the same performance as my handcrafted quicksort.  i.e. 1.83 seconds

Comment: @Michel Lemay: concerning boxing, the issue is that `Ordering` is generic, so all values of type `T` that go in and out of an `Ordering[T]` will *under the hood* be boxed (just like in java). Similarly, `Sorting.quickSort` is generic, so boxing happens there too. However scala has a feature called specialization that allows to avoid this boxing. So if **both** `Ordering` and `Sorting.quickSort` were specialized you would not have any boxing and this would result in a faster execution. You cannot modify the standard library to make them specialized, but you can use spire instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..I was exactly trying to figure out the difference between the two.  I guess it all boils down to the @sp annotations and having the right implicits.